# Task.Delay() hangs for minutes

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin, deadlock

I am developing Xamarin.iOS app and I am calling `await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, Task.Delay(msTimeout));` with msTimeout set to 8000. The problem is, that **sometimes** it is not completed in given 8000 ms delay and hangs for a few minutes (see the log).

I've read that using `task.Wait()` can cause this behavior, but I don't use it anywhere in my solution and I also removed it from Parse SDK opensourced library (but I guess it can still be used in some other not opensourced library..).

I also read that using `task.Result` can cause this, but I checked my solution and Parse library and it is only used in some `.ContinueWith(t => return t.Result)` or `.OnSuccess` situations which I think is ok (correct me if I'm wrong).

*I am also using SQLite and lately there's been some hangs with SQLite too, so it might be related to this issue. I was using SQLiteAsyncConnection singleton instance and SQLiteConnection singleton instance. I thought that using both is probably bad practice, so I've just managed to use only SQLiteAsyncConnection singleton instance, but it did not help.*

I also tried the "Break All" option in Visual Studio to see what line of code is next, but it always tells me "frame not in module".

Could you please share your ideas what else could cause these strange hangs in my app or how could I figure it out?

**EDIT:**
I've just discovered that the hanging Task.Delay is probably not the root cause of the hanging state and is hanging because the app gets into hanging state few seconds before. And it is indeed affecting SQLite too. I will continue investigating..

Code:

```
return await Task.Run(async () =>
   {
      try
      {
           Console.WriteLine("REMOTEREACHABLE 1");
           var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
           var hostEntry = new DnsEndPoint(host, port);
           Console.WriteLine("REMOTEREACHABLE 2");

           using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
           {
               Console.WriteLine("REMOTEREACHABLE 3");
               var socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs { RemoteEndPoint = hostEntry };
               socketEventArg.Completed += (s, e) =>
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("REMOTEREACHABLE COMPLETED:" + (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success));
                   tcs.TrySetResult(e.SocketError == SocketError.Success);
               };

               Console.WriteLine("REMOTEREACHABLE 4");
               socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);
               Console.WriteLine("REMOTEREACHABLE 5");
               await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, Task.Delay(msTimeout));
               if (!tcs.Task.IsCompleted)
                    Console.WriteLine("REMOTEREACHABLE TIMED OUT");
               var result = tcs.Task.IsCompleted && await tcs.Task;
               Console.WriteLine("REMOTEREACHABLE 6:" + result);
               return result;
           }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
            Debug.WriteLine("Unable to reach: " + host + " Error: " + ex);
            return false;
      }
});
```

Log:

```
2016-03-16 19:32:42.254 AppiOS[3309:6203] REMOTEREACHABLE 1
2016-03-16 19:32:42.259 AppiOS[3309:6203] REMOTEREACHABLE 2
2016-03-16 19:32:42.306 AppiOS[3309:6203] REMOTEREACHABLE 3
2016-03-16 19:32:42.319 AppiOS[3309:6203] REMOTEREACHABLE 4
Thread started:  #8
2016-03-16 19:32:43.039 AppiOS[3309:6203] REMOTEREACHABLE 5
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
Thread finished:  #8
Thread started:  #10
Thread finished:  #10
2016-03-16 19:34:05.471 AppiOS[3309:6203] REMOTEREACHABLE TIMED OUT
2016-03-16 19:34:05.478 AppiOS[3309:6203] REMOTEREACHABLE 6:False
```

Comment: This could happen if the thread pool is exhausted. Have you been able to reproduce in a minimal application? How about with desktop .NET?

Comment: @StephenCleary I did not try in minimal or desktop app, it would be very time consuming since it happens only simetimes and it would probably not help with finding the cause and solution (how would "it does not happen in desktop .NET" help me?). However, I'm calling this code few seconds after app launch so I guess it should not be exhausted. If the thread pool is exhausted, what can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: If you can get it reproducing reliably with a minimal example, it's usually easy to find the problem. This is the first step to solving any problem, whether it's your own or someone else's. Not doing it yourself just means that someone else has to do it. Re. Desktop .NET: Desktop uses a different BCL than Xamarin (for now), and most answerers have Desktop available but not Xamarin, so if you can get it broken on Desktop, your number of possible answerers increases significantly. Also, there have been (many) task/thread-related bugs found in Xamarin that are not present on Desktop.

Comment: I totally agree with @StephenCleary ! It would definitely help having the sufficient info enabling us to reproduce the issue and analyze it in standard Desktop/VS environment. Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out. It was most probably caused by the fact that `NetworkReachability.TryGetFlags` blocks the app on Xamarin.iOS when the network packet loss is 100% or when on wifi without internet. I was using Xamarin Connectivity plugin which calls the `TryGetFlags` inside. I described the issue [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/issues/275). Now I call it from new thread with return timeout and everything is ok.